# Ubuntu 18.04 Mouse Pointer Blinks and disappears on one screen after setting HiDPI scaling with xrandr

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, multi-monitor, xrandr

I use Ubuntu 18.04, on Dell XPS 15. There is a huge difference in the resolution of my screens, so when I plugged external monitors, either everything was too big on external monitors or everything was so small on laptop monitor. I used xrandr to setup the scaling as follows:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 1x1 --pos 0x2400
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --scale 2x2 --pos 0x350
xrandr --output DP-2-8 --scale 2x2 --pos 2560x0
```

eDP-1 is the laptop monitor with resolution 3840x2160, HDMI-1 is a VGA monitor with resolution 1280x1024, for which I use a VGA to HDMI converter to connect and DP-2-8 is another monitor with resolution 1920x1200 connected via display port. After doing this, mouse pointer started to blink, and even disappear only on eDP-1 but not on other screens, when CPU is in use. Let's say I open the settings window for Bluetooth, I cannot see mouse pointer, if I open an email, it blinks a couple of times and stabilizes. Does any one have similar problems or any idea what's going on?

Comment: I can confirm the exact same behaviour with my XPS 15 9570: xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale .5x.5 --mode 3840x2160 --output DP-1-2 --scale 1x1 --mode 2560x1440 --fb 6400x2880 --pos 0x0 --left-of eDP-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an xorg configuration file as mentioned [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics#Xorg_configuration) helped me to solve the problem.

Comment: I used this method to make xorg configuation file. https://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there

Comment: This answer is not really good enough to solve the problem. At least for newbie like me.

Answer (score 5):

Run the following xrandr command after yours:

```bsh
xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 0.9999x0.9999
```

Comment: This worked for me in Linux Mint; I don't know why, but it did.

Comment: Miraculous! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For users running Ubuntu 19.10, I can confirm that adding a configuration file by booting into recovery, selecting root shell, then running:

```
X -configure
```

Then entering:

```
cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

will both allow you to edit the configuration file, and fixes the common dual-monitor mouse flickering issue.

My current setup includes a Dell XPS 15 9560 with the high-res (4k) display, connected to a 1080p monitor.